# Camel route from Kafka to JMS not working (JMS->Kafka->JMS)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

In my Camel Router.java I have next routes

```
from("jms:topic:test.source.topic?asyncConsumer=true")
            .log("Message: ${body}")
            .to("kafka:testing?brokers=192.168.0.100:9092");

from("kafka:testing?brokers=192.168.0.100:9092")
            .log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}")
            .log("    on the topic ${headers[kafka.TOPIC]}")
            .log("    on the partition ${headers[kafka.PARTITION]}")
            .log("    with the offset ${headers[kafka.OFFSET]}")
            .log("    with the key ${headers[kafka.KEY]}")
            // manually set JMSDeliveryMode (1 - NON_PERSISTENT, 2 - PERSISTENT)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMSDeliveryMode", "1");
               }
            })
            .to("jms:topic:test.sink.topic");
```

Problem appears with above Camel routes. If I send some message to topic `testing` with Kafka producer that I run with `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic testing --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`, routing from Kafka to JMS is working fine. So it is some problem with those linked Camel routes.

In Camel pom.xml are Spring Boot camel-kafka-starter and camel-jms-starter dependencies.

When I start Spring Boot Camel with Maven and send some message from Kafka producer to Kafka broker `testing` topic, I can see that message is recieved by Kafka broker and above logs are printed OK.

Error appears on line `.to("jms:topic:test.sink.topic");` and I don't know what it means.

```
ERROR 28642 --- [aConsumer[testing]] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler: Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-PCID on ExchangeId: ID-PCID). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ139015: Illegal deliveryMode value: 0

org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ139015: Illegal deliveryMode value: 0
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:525) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:438) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:392) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:155) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:168) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:40) ~[camel-support-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.doRun(KafkaConsumer.java:346) ~[camel-kafka-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:222) ~[camel-kafka-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ139015: Illegal deliveryMode value: 0
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(ActiveMQMessage.java:450) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessageHelper.setJMSDeliveryMode(JmsMessageHelper.java:435) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.appendJmsProperty(JmsBinding.java:393) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.appendJmsProperties(JmsBinding.java:371) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.makeJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:346) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer$2.createMessage(JmsProducer.java:325) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:561) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.lambda$send$0(JmsConfiguration.java:527) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504) ~[spring-jms-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

When sending some message from JMS to Kafka, routing is working fine.

Comment: I've updated the question with full error record, Camel routes and more information about the problem. Running maven with -e and -X is not giving me more details about the error.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant error message:

```
AMQ139015: Illegal deliveryMode value: 0
```

This error message means that something has invoked the JMS method [`javax.jms.Message#setJMSDeliveryMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSDeliveryMode-int-) with a value of `0`. The value of `0` is not valid. Valid delivery mode values are defined by [`javax.jms.DeliveryMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/DeliveryMode.html):

- [`1` (for non-persistent)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.jms.DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
- [`2` (for persistent)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT).

The stack-trace indicates that this invalid value is being set by Camel based on the input message. See [this code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.4.0/components/camel-jms/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsBinding.java#L366). In order to fix the problem you need to determine where the header `JMSDeliveryMode` is being set on the `org.apache.camel.Message`.

Comment: I did not determine exactly where header `JMSDeliveryMode` is changed. In Camel route from JMS to Kafka, I added log of getHeader() and saw `JMSDeliveryMode=1`. Also did the same in Camel route from Kafka to JMS and saw `{JMSDeliveryMode=[B@6069793c ...` and `... kafka.HEADERS=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = JMSDeliveryMode, value = [0, 0, 0, 1]) ...`.

Comment: As a solution (I assume not a good one), in Camel route from Kafka to JMS I've added a process and set `JMSDeliveryMode` manually like updated code in question above.